# NSString crash when I don't have emoji in my string

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, nsstring, emoji

I have a conversational view on my application.
I want to display emoji on the good way in this view.
So I stock my text on a NSString create with the parameter encoding set to : "NSStringEncoding.NonLossyASCII".
It works when I have an emoji on my string.
But when there is no emoji on the string, there is a crash with the log :

> Exception masked Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the
>   type 'Foundation.NSString': the native 'initWithData:encoding:' method
>   returned nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false. at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_bool
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,bool) at
>   Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread (System.Action action)
>   [0x00007] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3988/e02d2723/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:560

Is it possible to check if there's emoji on a string or not?
Thank you

Comment: i'm not really sure but why do you need to set NSStringEncoding.NonLossyASCII ? doesn't emoji works without it ? i was able to add the emoji to the common (standard) string.

Comment: If I don't specify encoding, emoji display has a text like : "\ud83d"

Answer (score 1):

There is no way emojis can be expressed using [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (it is ancient and contains only 128 essential characters). For this reason string initialization fails (as suggested by the error message). Use another encoding (`NSUTF8StringEncoding` should work).

Comment: I already try UTF8 but it doesn't works, it display my message with "\ud83d \ude02" in place of the emoji. The non-lossy ASCII display the emoji, the problem is why does it make my app crash when there's no emoji in my text...

Comment: For the moment, I bypass the problem like this : 
'
try
    {
     msgString = new NSString(msg.Content, NSStringEncoding.NonLossyASCII);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     msgString = new NSString(msg.Content);
    }
'

But I don't find this really classy...

Comment: @nicar what do you mean by "display the emoji"?

Comment: The emoji appear like an emoji and not like a code has "\ude02", without NSStringEncoding.NonLossyASCII, the emoji appears like text code.

Comment: I found this example in swift https://gist.github.com/NarayanaRao35/3a69527a746e6cd688c21838e38e2e21 
But in C# I don't have any access to the raw value of an encoding and the exception occurred in the decoding, I don't have a return value like null. So I think I can't do the same.